# Why was this typo question reopened?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10087628/4284627) ([web archive for <10k users](http://web.archive.org/web/20190421154615/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087628/javascript-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier)) looks to me like something that should clearly be closed: it dumps a piece of code with several typos and asks why there is a syntax error. So I voted to close it and asked for it to be closed in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). Two other users voted to close it, so it was closed and I thought that was the end of the story.

But today I saw that the question was reopened, and I can't figure out why anyone would vote to reopen it. To me the only thing that distinguishes that question from other typo questions is that it has a positive score, but I always assumed that that's because it was posted when Stack Overflow was smaller and more tolerant of bad questions.

Am I missing something that makes this a good question? Or was it incorrectly reopened?

Comment: It could be closed as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871616/what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-operators-and-what-is-si...

Comment: I have no idea; probably only the three users who voted to reopen it would be able to explain why they did so. In any case, it's closed again now.

Comment: it was reopened from review, after a 3/2 result. It can be difficult to recognize "typos" from review, given the nature of typos.

Comment: @HereticMonkey not exactly a dupe, since it's missing an opening bracket in `if result = "Lambourghini Aventador")`. But the dupe is still very relevant to why the code wouldn't work after that typo is fixed.

Comment: I have another question related to that one - why was it in the reopen queue at all? Seems like somebody found it and voted to reopen. Which would be odd. The reopen queue was actually split on it, too: 3 reopen / 2 leave closed.

Comment: Based on the review, i'd hazard a guess that noone voted to reopen it at all prior to review, all of the votes on it came from reviews. Some automatic process? I don't see an edit..

Comment: Also... the review opened almost exacty a minute after it was closed... surely it was some automatic process that sends older upvoted posts to review automatically

Comment: To be fair, the only reason that close reason exists, is for the "_this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers_". Those upvotes weren't there the day it was posted. They were gathered over time. So apparently, people have found this post and somehow found it useful (which I find mind-blowing).

Comment: @Ivar I don't understand how that's mind-blowing. Someone gets the error. Lands on that page. Sees what the problem is and go "Ahh.. That's what I did. Now I know what mistake I made. Thank, I'll upvote that". I thought that's what the site was for.

Comment: This question clearly has been in front of search engines: 71k views, so it's one of those inadvertent "canonical" posts that happens to have a good title that describes a common error. It's nice that OP provided their full code, but the problem is that it's not minimal and exhibits multiple issues, both logical and syntactical. Also, they forgot to show the full error message with line number. There are plenty of clearer posts that are more helpful for each of the errors here and therefore more deserving of page views.

Comment: @Scratte Of course. That would be the case for most (long lasting) posts on SO. But this specific error can be thrown for basically any abnormality in the syntax (which I assume causes the large amount of views). It surprises me that so many find the correction of those specific typo's in that question so useful.

Comment: @Ivar I've made that exact mistake more than a few times myself :)

Comment: The problem is, it's not "that exact same mistake". It's at least 3 different mistakes. If there's a common mistake in there, we should have a more appropriate canonical that covers *just that mistake*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The question entered the "Reopen" review queue on October 18, 2021 at 11:41 UTC. The reason for its enqueueing was "PopularClosedQuestion". The outcome of [the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/30108144) was 3/2, in favor of reopening. So, the question was re-opened.

In case you're wondering why "PopularClosedQuestion" would be a reason to enqueue a question in the Reopen review queue, join the club. [It is, though.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078) A question that is sufficiently popular, as determined by the score of the question itself, *or* the score of the top answer, *or* the number of views per month is automatically enqueued for reopening. Despite the fact that none of these things really suggest that a question has magically become suitable for this site.

<strike>I tried to delete it, but it's had other questions closed as a duplicate of it (*why??!!*), so that is not possible. I would ask that some Javascript folks assist with some clean-up here, reversing whatever wrong-headedness led to the closing of questions as a duplicate of a useless typo (what *isn't* wrong) question, either re-opening them, closing them as typos, or closing them as duplicates of an appropriate canonical. At that point, we can delete this question.</strike>

It's deleted now, along with [the question that was closed as a duplicate of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712661/cant-fix-error-code-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier-using-jquery), since both of these questions were "typo" questions with little or no use to future viewers.

If someone wants to argue that [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087628/how-to-fix-an-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier-error) should be retained as a stub, due to its notably high view count, please let me know which canonical it would be appropriate to close it as a duplicate of and I will happily do so.